# weird interpolation using filledcurves

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 4 nan
4 5 6
```

I want to plot it using:

```
plot "bla" u 1:2:3 w filledcurves, "" u 1:2 w lp, "" u 1:3 w lp
```

The problem is that the first part totally ignores the 3rd line, even though the nan is only in $3. Even though I have a value (4) in $2, it interpolates and skips it.

How do I make it not ignore that value?

I can make a workaround by replacing the nan by the value that should be there- (3+6)/2 in my case and then it will plot the 4 as well. There are two problems with that - I'll have to write a script that finds nans around the file, and it also plots a point when I'm using `w lp` as if there is a value there, but there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking gnuplot's using to do something that it wasn't designed to do.  Fortunately, there's a somewhat hacky solution.  You need to use the 2-column version of filled curves which considers your data-points to make a closed loop.  In this case, you want to plot the stuff from columns 1 and 2 and then the stuff from columns 3 and 1 (in reverse order).  e.g.:

```
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 5
4 6
3 nan
2 3
1 2
```

If your datafile looks like this, you can plot it as:

```
plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w filledcurves
```

Now I'm pretty sure you don't actually want to re-generate your data-files, so the easiest thing is to use unix tools to do it for you:

```
plot "< sed 'x;1!H;$!d;x' test.dat | awk '{print $1,$3}' | cat test.dat -" u 1:2 w filledcurves
```

This should work.  Note that the ugly `sed` command can be replaced by `tac` if you have that installed.

Comment: Actually I'm asking gnuplot's using to do exactly what it was designed to do. 3 columns in filledcurves should fill the area between two curves. From the algorithm's perspective, since it has no top and bottom at that point then it shouldn't plot anything, but from the user's perspective, it shouldn't matter. Thinking about it, it's more of a bug or non-existent feature in gnuplot.
However, your workaround works just fine.

Comment: @Michael -- No, this is definitely not what it was designed to do.  `using` was designed to parse a single record at a time (in your case, columns 1,2, and 3).  If any element in that record is not readible, gnuplot discards the entire record.  This is extremely useful behavior for *most* plot types.  (e.g. consider plotting a 3d scatter plot -- If you know "x" and "y", but not "z" you still can't plot the point).  Cases like this one would need to be handled specially and would probably make the code-base a lot more difficult to manage.